# APC enabled throught localhost to www.localhost

Tags: php, wamp, apc

i am using WAMP, with php 5.2.9 and facing strange problem in my localhost, I recently enabled apc into the wamp server.

But When i try to open my CMS(like wordpress, joomla) it through localhost to www.localhost.com and my wamp server goes OFFLINE but not with the core files MEANS i have a website in CORE PHP and it's open properly without and www redirect,  Can anyone help me to detect the exact problem?

Answer (score 1):

www.localhost.com is not in your hosts file (most likely). localhost is. If you intend on accessing your site through that URL you need to edit your "hosts" file and append www.localhost.com to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Sorry, your English is terrible^ and i am only guessing at your problem. Could you edit it and make it more clear?